# get request from Openweathermap returns (404) not found

Tags: c#, get, http-status-code-404, openweathermap

I'm trying to get weather info with following code, but every time (except first, but I'm not sure) I getting 404 responce. What I'm doing wrong?

CityName = "Omsk";
            API_KEY = "368e827be4b38db51ff960ca88b5c396";

```
        weburl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + CityName + "&mode=xml&APPID=" + API_KEY;
        //weburl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&APPID=368e827be4b38db51ff960ca88b5c396";

        doc = new XmlDocument ();

        var xml = new WebClient().DownloadString(new Uri (weburl));
        doc.LoadXml (xml);
        foreach(XmlNode node in doc.GetElementsByTagName("*"))
        {
             Console.Out.WriteLine(node.Name);
        }
```

Comment: Works fine for me. You do not want to post your personal API_KEY here, consider editing yor questions to replace it by some placeholder.

Comment: it is free key, so I'm not very scared about it. Now I have one idea. One interesting thing, that I can't do some things on Openweather web page without enabling VPN. May bee that's the problem?

Comment: I got the same error and had to send the request over `https`